# Sorted copy construction for ArrayList

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList`.
How can I instantiate a new `List` with the same data but **sorted**?
I thought about the following:

1. Use the `ArrayList` copy constructor and then use `Collections.sort`
2. Use a `TreeSet`

For option (1) there is the extra overhead of copying the elements and *then* sorting.
For option (2) duplicates will be removed.
What is the best way for this?

Comment: Assuming you want those duplicates, use option 1. There's no better way I can suggest, unless you can provide us more details about the data it contains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "best way" depends on your requirements: do you want the duplicates removed? Use a `TreeSet`; do you want to keep the duplicates? Copy, then sort. Trying to get the fastest one out of the two is premature optimization.

Answer (score 9):

If you can use third-party libraries, then with [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) this is just

```
List<Foo> sortedCopy = Ordering.from(comparator).sortedCopy(list);
```

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: Or [immutableSortedCopy](https://guava.dev/releases/32.0.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#immutableSortedCopy(java.lang.Iterable)) for an immutable copy.

Answer (score 7):

In Java 8 you can use streaming:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList();
myArrayList.add(4);
myArrayList.add(6);

List<Integer> myNewSortedList = myArrayList.stream().sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, the list above must not be mutated. If you want that, you can instead collect into an `ArrayList`:

```java
List<Integer> myNewSortedList = myArrayList.stream().sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: s/asList/toList/

Comment: Starting with Java 16, you can use [`.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) instead of `.collect(Collectors.toList())`: `myArrayList.stream().sorted().toList()`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a `Treeset` to get a sorted copy of a `List`.  It'll remove duplicates.  (Unless this is what's desired, but then it's a different problem from creating a new sorted copy of a `List`).

Use option 1 - Create a new `List` and call `Collections.sort()` on it, and possibly use your own `Comparator` if desired.