# Cant add ArrayList contents to same type of ArrayList

Tags: java

I have 2 ArrayLists:

```
private List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();
private List<Client> sortedClientList = new ArrayList<Client>();
```

I sort `clientList` like this:

```
clientList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Client::getScore));
```

What I want to do, is to "clone" all the content in the same order to the sortedClientList, but I'm doing something wrong.
I tried `sortedClientList.add(clientList.sort(Comparator...` and `sortedClientList.addAll(clientList.sort(Comparator...` however I get the error `The method add(Client) in the type List<Client> is not applicable for the arguments (void)`

My goal is to have a sorted list but in a separate object, thus `sortedClientList`

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at what does `clientList.sort(...)` return?

Comment: It returns a list of objects, sorted by the 'score' field, if that's what you are asking, sorry.

Comment: No, it does not. The error is pretty clear about what `clientList.sort` returns: it returns `void`.

Comment: It does [not](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is of type `void` meaning it doesn't return an object and therefore you cannot pass it as it if were an object.

```
clientList.sort(...)
```

this method sorts the elements of the `clientList`, it does not create a copy of `clientList` with the elements sorted.

What you're looking for is to make a sorted copy of the `clientList`, a similar question is posed here: [Sorted copy construction for ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726696/sorted-copy-construction-for-arraylist)

Answer (score 1):

Method `sort` sorts the list and returns nothing (a.k.a. `void`).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-